# Problem serving static files from vue build on a wordpress server

Tags: wordpress, vue.js, vue-cli, static-files

I need to put the generated static files from a vue build inside a WordPress page, in theory, it should've been an easy quest, but the static files "have a problem" with the paths to resources like assets, CSS files, and js files.

Example: If you build a Vue project and open the index.html on the live server (vscode extension), the page will be fully white and the developer's tools will show that the resources were not loaded.

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Looking at index.html, I discovered that if I add a "." in front of the paths inside every `href`, the resources a loaded.
Basically, if I change this

```
<link href=/css/chunk-vendors.fb624d12.css rel=preload as=style>
```

to this

```
<link href=./css/chunk-vendors.fb624d12.css rel=preload as=style>
```

The **chunk-vendors.fb624d12.css** file will be loaded. But this is a very impractical solution because I have many CSS and js files, so I really want to find an optimized solution for this.

Comment: Where are you putting your built files? Is it inside of a plugin template? A theme? In the root directory (`public_html`)? Are you using Vue Router? If so, are you using history mode?

Comment: @SuitBoyApps I'm putting the built files inside a sub-folder in the root directory of the main webpage, for exemple, I have the main wordpress page and it's url is something like `my-college-library.com`, so the page that I want to deploy would be in `my-college-library.com/sub-folder/`. And no, I'm not using Vue Router, should I? I'm fairly new to Vue.js